# How to get attribute value of an element in Playwright Python

Tags: python, selenium, playwright

I'm using Playwright Python for a project. I'm trying to get the '*href*' attribute value of an element.

For *Selenium*, I used

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a")
link = el.get_attribute('href')
```

What is the equivalent to the above code in **Playwright**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the href in an almost similar way to that of selenium.

```
element_handle = page.locator("//a")
link = element_handle.get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: The documentation at https://playwright.dev/python/docs/evaluating gives a good example of getting this the canonical way too.

Comment: `page.locator("a")` is simpler, or `page.get_by_role("link")`. XPath is discouraged by Playwright.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use this code to obtain and print all the hrefs elements of a page.
Empty field if it doesn't exist.
I'm sure that then, you can obtain the element that you need

```
const urls = await page.$$eval('a', (elements) =>
   elements.map((el) => el.href),
   )
for await (const u of urls) {
   console.log("URLS: " + u)
}
```

Comment: This is not python