# Getting value of input element

Tags: playwright, playwright-python, playwright-test

```html
<input datatype="1" id="me9f88f1d-tb" aria-readonly="true" role="textbox" class="fld text text    fld fld_ro" ctype="textbox" li="me9f88f1d-img" maxlength="10" style=";width:12.100000000000001ch;" sue="1" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="3510823" work="1" title="3510823" originalvalue="3510823" prekeyvalue="3510823" stoptcclick="true">
```

I have an input in which I'm trying to capture the text by value="3510823" or title="3510823" and store it in a variable through Playwright (Python)

```
 reg = page.wait_for_selector("#me9f88f1d-tb").text_content()
    print (reg)
```

There is no error, however, the print is blank.

I would like to store the value, in this case "3510823" in a variable

(Translated by Google Translate)

Comment: Did you try `input_value` instead of `text_content`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get attribute value of an element in Playwright Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716831/how-to-get-attribute-value-of-an-element-in-playwright-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to capture the value, with:

```
selector = '(//input[@id="me9f88f1d-tb"])[1]'
reg_dup = page.eval_on_selector(selector, "(element) => element.value")
```

thanks